# How do I make the proxy ignore the url prefix when using caddy or nginx?

Tags: nginx, caddy

I know how to add a prefix to the proxy, but I don't know how to ignore it.

For example:
I hope that when I access `/api/users`, caddy or nginx can help me proxy to `/users`.

How can I configure it?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Try using the `without` subdirective of proxy: `without /api` (docs: https://caddyserver.com/docs/proxy)